# is there a way to have multiple connection strings for branches in bamboo?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, svn, bamboo

Running continuous integration with bamboo, using sql server 2008.
Is there a way to have multiple connection strings for branches in bamboo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  But not directly like you might think.  Do this.  Create multiple Web.config files named like Web.Test.config, Web.QA.config, Web.Stage.config, Web.Prod.config, etc.  Each of these has the connection strings, and other settings, needed in each of those environments.  After your build and deploy, by branch, use an Ant/NAnt script to replace the Web.config with the one you want for that environment.

I assume that is what you mean.  Question is a bit vague.